# how to use structure variables with scanf

Tags: c++

hey guys sorry for butting in... but i've got some problems with scanf as well... i'm not a frequent user of scanf but i like it... i don't know where i've gone wrong but evry time i run the pgm i keep getting the same values for to different char variables in a structure... pls help....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct staff{
    int id;
    char name[];
    char dept[];
};
struct worker{
    int h_no;
    char h_addr[];
    staff emp;
}w;
int main(){
    cout<<"Enter worker details: ";
    printf("\nID: ");
    scanf("%d", &w.emp.id);
    printf("\nName: ");
    scanf("%s", w.emp.name);
    printf("\nDept: ");
    scanf("%s",w.emp.dept);
    system("cls");
    printf("ID: %d \nName: %s \nDept: %s \n", w.emp.id,w.emp.name,w.emp.dept);
```

Comment: why you are not using `cin`

Comment: Decide if you are using C or C++ first. If you truly want to use C++ then you should be using `std::cin` and `std::cout` for your terminal I/O instead of `scanf()` and `printf()`, and you should use `std::string` instead of character arrays. Just because you *can* use C functions from C++ does not make it a good idea in all cases. Use the facilities C++ provides over comparable facilities C provides unless you have a *very* compelling reason not to.

Comment: @Shan i just thought i'd try something new..... thats all... but is there something wrong with using scanf ???

Comment: @cdhowie i want use c++.... but i've already mentioned "using namespace std" globally so do i have to use std::__ again? i'm sorry but i didn't quiet understand what you meant after that???

Comment: @EdwinCharles I mean that you apparently are using the C++ language, but you continue to do things "the C way." If you're going to use C++ then do things the C++ way.

Comment: oh ok now i get it thanx @cdhowie .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly considering your definition for struct `staff`,

```
struct staff{
  int id;
  char name[];
  char dept[];
};
```

when I execute to get the address for char arrays I see they point to same random location as below which is the reason for your output being always same for `name` & `dept`.

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter worker details: 
ID: 1
Name: stack
Dept: overflow
address of w.emp.name: 0x601188 
address of w.emp.dept: 0x601188
Output:
ID: 1 
Name: overflow 
Dept: overflow
```

Assigning memory for each array as,

```
struct staff{
  int id;
  char name[10];
  char dept[10];
};
```

this time the addresses are valid,

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter worker details: 
ID: 1
Name: stack
Dept: overflow
address of w.emp.name: 0x601188 
address of w.emp.dept: 0x601192
Output:
ID: 1 
Name: stack 
Dept: overflow
```

Hence you need to allocate memory to your char arrays well before based on your requirement, otherwise the base address of the arrays are strangely pointing to same memory location causing the later stdin input string at any point of time.

Answer (score 1):

You have already included `<iostream>`, why don't you use `std::cin` and `std::cout`?

Here is a slightly modernized version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct staff{
    int id = 0;
    std::string name;
    std::string dept;
};

struct worker{
    int h_no = 0;
    std::string h_addr;
    staff emp;
};

int main(){
    worker w;
    std::cout << "Enter worker details: ";
    std::cout << "\nID: ";
    if (!(std::cin >> w.emp.id)) {
         std::cout << "ID entry failed." << std::endl;
         return -1;
    }
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cout << "Name: ";
    if (!std::getline(std::cin, w.emp.name)) {
         std::cout << "Name entry failed." << std::endl;
         return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Dept: ";
    if (!std::getline(std::cin, w.emp.dept)) {
         std::cout << "Dept entry failed." << std::endl;
         return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "ID: " << w.emp.id
              << " Name: " << w.emp.name
              << " Dept: " << w.emp.dept << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good, though I would also suggest adding tests on input to make sure that the input succeeded. (`if (!(std::cin >> w.emp.id)) { /* handle error */ }`) If the input fails an the variable being read is uninitialized (as is the case with `w.emp.id`) then using that value later in the final statement using `std::cout` is undefined behavior. Further, you don't return a value from `int main()` leaving the program's exit code unspecified.

Comment: Thanks @cdhowie, I added the tests. It will implicitly return 0 if it reaches the end without encountering any return statements but I edited that too...

Comment: Note that there is still UB if you fail to read into `w.emp.id` because you don't prevent it from reaching the final `std::cout` and accessing `w.emp.id` before it's been initialized in the failure case. And no, the return value from a function is *undefined* if execution reaches the end of the function without encountering a `return` statement (except, of course, in functions returning `void`).

Comment: @mete You're right about return 0 from main... unnecessary (and a pet peeve here).  From C++11 onwards, if `std::cin >> w.emp.id` fails it will still set `w.emp.id` to `0`, so it's safe to output that field, and `string`s get default constructed anyway so are never uninitialised.  Anyway, I'd suggest simply `if (std::cin >> w.emp.id && std::getline(std::cin, w.emp.name) && std::getline(std::cin, w.emp.dept)) std::cout << ...cout...; else ...report error...;`, as names of people and departments might be multi-word.

Comment: @TonyD your suggestions are great but it does not give feedback about what information to enter when inside a single if.

Comment: @cdhowie all except `id` are default initialized to blank string. I'll add default initialization to 0 for the id to make sure it does not show undefined behavior. You are wrong about the `main` being undefined, it is an exception, and it implicitly returns 0.

Comment: @mete: oh yeah - forgot to intersperse `&& std::cout << "ID: " &&` etc. in there: best broken across lines for readability.  No point doing what you're doing though - ignoring errors and trying to continue... who knows what you'll end up printing or how meaningful it'll be.

Comment: @TonyD alright, I'll return prematurely then. I was planning to show the asker the C++ version of his simple C code without any promise of error checking, etc. but it turned into a complicated exercise compared to his, which may be a bit intimidating  about the usage of `std::cin` and `std::cout` instead to `scanf` and `printf`...

Comment: @mete: yeah... `iostream`s have many good points, but they're on the fiddly and verbose side of `cstdio`.... :-/  Still, I wouldn't bother with `ignore` or `clear` - less verbose ala `if (std::cout << "ID: " && std::cin >> w.emp.id && std::cout << "Name: " && std::getline(std::cin, w.emp.name) && std::cout << "Dept: " && std::getline(std::cin, w.emp.dept)) std::cout << ...cout...; else ...report error...;`, which is what I meant by interspersing the output above.  Lots of people would think my use of `&&` excessive and cryptic - hard to win.

Comment: @TonyD, IO and its difficulties... First time you call `std::getline`, it gets the residual `\n` from entering the integer in the `std::cin`, so there should also be a `std::cin.ignore()` inside that big parenthesis with `&&`'s. I agree that the version you are proposing looks good but I am removing those now-extraneous `ignore`s and `clear`s and stopping editing since it is still looking relatively similar to the asker's version :)

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said it's a better idea to use cin/cout, but I would still like to answer your initial question so that you actually gain understanding of what's going on and what's wrong with your code.

The strings that you read from the standard input using scanf (or cin for that matter) occupy physical bytes. They have to be stored somewhere. There has to be a special place allocated in the computer's memory for that string, just enough bytes to store all the characters.

The problem with how you define your structs is that simply writing `char name[]` and `char dept[]` does not allocate space for the string. In fact, it doesn't allocate any space at all (or maybe allocates 1 byte, I don't quite remember the details, but it's not that important in this context).

Roughly what happens in your call to scanf is you tell it "read characters from standard input while possible, then write them to memory starting at this location". "This location" in your case means the single byte in memory corresponding to the "name" field. But since there is no memory allocated for the string, scanf writes data beyond the "borders" of your object, with unpredictable results (this is called "undefined behavior").

How do you actually allocate memory for your strings? Well, you can do something like this:

```
struct staff{
    int id;
    char name[100];
    char dept[100];
};
```

But it's bad because

1) the maximum length is limited to a hundred characters

2) it wastes space if your strings are shorter than 100 characters

3) most important, there is no way to tell scanf to only read up to 100 chars: it will just read and read, and if the input is longer than 100 chars, it will go beyond the border of the struct and it will be undefined behavior again. [This can be actually used by people to trick your program into doing things it was not intended to do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Microsoft actually has [secure scanf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) in its version of the standard library.

Using std::string and cin/cout will save you a lot of headache because they handle a lot of stuff behind the scenes for you (such as dynamically allocating the necessary amount of memory, etc.)

It's still important to understand what I've written above. I know it can seem daunting, but it's really not that hard, you just have to remind yourself that everything is just an ephemeral abstraction, the only things that are real are the processor (with its instruction set) and the memory.